# passing " in html value

Tags: html, input

I've a variable like:

```
<?php
$val = 'abc"def\'ad';
?>
```

my html is like:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" name="xyz" />
```

But the input can't show all the text because having " or ' in the middle of them. But I need the text field to show abc"def'ad . Any idea how to do it using HTML (not js)?

Comment: may useful to use `\\\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your PHP variable:

```
$val = htmlspecialchars('abc"def\'ad');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
   $val = htmlspecialchars('abc"def\'ad');
?>
```

Comment: This answer was already there. It looks like copy paste of doitlikejustin's answer

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra : often it happens in stack overflow..many people answers in same time..so conflicts occurs bro..but it is not intensional..

Comment: Stackoverflow timestamps answers, there is a difference of 7 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  $val = 'abc"def'.' \' '. 'ad';
?>
```

It is easy and simple. Hope it helps.